# Prove that the Gauss map is strong-mixing.

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let  $X=[0,1]\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ and define the Gauss map $T:X\rightarrow X$ by
\begin{equation*}
T(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}-\left\lfloor\dfrac{1}{x}\right\rfloor
\end{equation*} where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $t$. 
Prove that Gauss map is strong-mixing with respect to the Gauss measure $\mu(A)=\dfrac{1}{\text {log}2} {\displaystyle \int_A }\dfrac{1}{1+x}dx$.

Let $T$ be a measure-preserving tranformation of a probability space $(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$. We say that  $T$ is strong-mixing if $\forall A,B \in $
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(T^{-n}A\cap B)=\mu(A)\mu(B).$

Comment: I dont have any idea. I only can prove that Gauss map is ergodic.

Comment: Can you link the proof that this map is Ergodic?